# In C#, is there a way (maybe using Reflection) which I can simplify creating Mocks for dependencies with dependencies?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, moq, xunit

We have classes which don't have interfaces.  As (1) I don't want to touch the production code; and (2) I don't believe it is a great practice to have interfaces only to facilitate testing, I'm trying to figure out whether or how I can simplify the process of creating Mocks for these classes which may not have empty constructors and may not be virtual.

For example, I have an API controller which has a dependency which needs to be mocked out, but this in turn has a rat's nest of further dependencies.  So, to create an instance of my controller with mocks, I have the following code:

```
        private static ContractDocuSignCallbackController CreateControllerUnderTest(Dictionary<Type, object> classDependenciesByType)
        {
            Mock<DocuSignCallbackHandler> mockDocuSignCallbackHandler = CreateMockDocuSignCallbackHander(classDependenciesByType);
            return new(mockDocuSignCallbackHandler.Object);

            Mock<DocuSignCallbackHandler> CreateMockDocuSignCallbackHander(Dictionary<Type, object> classDependenciesByType)
            {
                Mock<ContractDAO> mockContractDAO = new(
                                TestUtilities.GetOrCreateSetting<ContractDatabaseSettings>(classDependenciesByType),
                                TestUtilities.GetOrCreateMock<IMongoDatabase>(classDependenciesByType)
                            );
                Mock<ContractLister> mockContractLister = new(mockContractDAO.Object);
                SalesforceFieldNames salesforceFieldNames = TestUtilities.GetOrCreateSetting<SalesforceFieldNames>(classDependenciesByType);
                Mock<SalesforceContractResolver> mockSalesforceContractResolver = new(salesforceFieldNames);
                Mock<DocuSignCommonHelpers> mockDocuSignCommonHelpers = new(
                    mockContractDAO.Object,
                    TestUtilities.GetOrCreateMock<ILogger<DocuSignCommonHelpers>>(classDependenciesByType),
                    TestUtilities.GetOrCreateMock<ISalesforceCacheQuerier>(classDependenciesByType),
                    mockSalesforceContractResolver.Object,
                    salesforceFieldNames,
                    TestUtilities.GetOrCreateMock<MultipurposeResultFactory>(classDependenciesByType)
                );
                Mock<SfContractWriteDataFactory> mockSfContractWriteDataFactory = new(
                    TestUtilities.GetOrCreateSetting<SalesforceFieldValues>(classDependenciesByType)
                );
                Mock<DocuSignCallbackHandler> mockDocuSignCallbackHandler = new(
                        mockContractLister.Object,
                        mockDocuSignCommonHelpers.Object,
                        TestUtilities.GetOrCreateMock<IEnvelopeService>(classDependenciesByType),
                        TestUtilities.GetOrCreateMock<IHttpContextAccessor>(classDependenciesByType),
                        TestUtilities.GetOrCreateMock<IImageSaver>(classDependenciesByType),
                        TestUtilities.GetOrCreateSetting<ImageLinkRenewerSettings>(classDependenciesByType),
                        TestUtilities.GetOrCreateMock<ISalesforceCacheSyncDataManipulator>(classDependenciesByType),
                        TestUtilities.GetOrCreateMock<MultipurposeResultFactory>(classDependenciesByType),
                        mockSalesforceContractResolver.Object,
                        mockSfContractWriteDataFactory.Object
                );
                return mockDocuSignCallbackHandler;
            }
        }
```

The parameter `Dictionary<Type, object> classDependenciesByType` allows me to control any of the dependencies I actually care about, whereas frequently I don't care about many at all (never mind what this suggests about the separation of concerns, which admittedly could use work).

My utility class looks like this:

```
    class TestUtilities
    {
        public static T GetOrCreateMock<T>(Dictionary<Type, object> classDependenciesByType)
            where T : class => classDependenciesByType.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out object dependency)
                ? (T)dependency
                : new Mock<T>().Object;

        public static T GetOrCreateSetting<T>(Dictionary<Type, object> classDependenciesByType)
            where T : class => classDependenciesByType.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out object dependency)
                ? (T)dependency
                : Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    }
```

Would it be possible to use reflection or some other feature of C# in order to do this without making every dependency explicit, which is not only tedious but potentially fragile?

Comment: If you have to do so much work you're mocking the wrong thing. Or the thing you're mocking is trying to do too many things at once.

Comment: "I don't believe it is a great practice to have interfaces only to facilitate testing" well there's your problem. If you had interfaces, all this testing complexity would fall away.

Comment: Instead of trying to mock all dependencies why not create some dummy objects? .NET Core's logging has a NullLogger already, just for testing. It should be easy to create a dummy Data Access Object as well, perhaps even a "smart" one that stores stuff in a Dictionary<TKey,TWhatever>. EF Core uses the in-memory provider for this

Comment: I guess you are not using dependency injection "just for testing" either? You can't (easily) test arbitrary code, code should be written with possibility of testing in mind.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I did not create all the original code.  Yes, there is not the best separation of concerns, so frequently the solution may have dependencies I should not care about for particular methods.  You'll need to be more explicit regarding your suggestion to use dummy objects, but for better or for worse, most of the constructors have null checks on all the parameters.

Comment: @DavidG, https://blog.hovland.xyz/2017-04-22-stop-overusing-interfaces/

Comment: Look into Microsoft Fakes. This requires enterprise edition of Visual Studio but will give you what you're after.

Comment: @Evk, Yes, we have dependency injection.  However, when there is only one real implementation of the dependency, it is just noise which makes the code harder to work with to have interfaces.  It's files to maintain and turns the IDE into a labrynth when you try to click on methods.

Comment: @BrianKessler From that article: *The point of this article is not to say that using DI with interfaces is bad. My point is that you shouldn’t automatically put interfaces on everything without thinking, but certainly use them when you need them.*

Comment: But also, I can find lots of articles out there that "prove" the earth is flat, doesn't mean they're correct either.

Comment: If you use dependency injection, then you have some place where you register all dependencies in some DI container. Why not do the same for test code? Register all dependencies once in a container (some can be mocks), then resolve whatever you need to test and test it.

Comment: @DavidG, You seem to have missed everything else Tor had to say.  At this point, the solution is what it is and I would prefer not to touch the production code neither for the sake of adding interfaces nor to make things virtual.

Comment: @Evk, I don't want to add complexity to the tests which can (and likely will) become another potential point of failure.  And I certainly don't want to create something which will need to be updated whenever any of the dependencies anywhere changes.  I want something which can simply instantiate mocks of all the objects which are necessary to instantiate the object under test, including anything those objects may also need, etc.

Comment: `potential point of failure` The test has already failed - that mocking code requires testing itself. That's why you posted a question here. `the solution is what it is` which is *not* trying to mock every single dependency. The code you posted is what code looked before DI containers became popular. Instead of trying to mock everything why not use DI and register either mock or fake objects? Instead of that `ILogger<>`, use a `NullLogger`. Instead of an actual DAO create a fake one that writes to a Dictionary. All those factory methods can be registered in any DI container.

Comment: @BrianKessler which DI container are you using? Configuration and logging libraries? If you use .NET Core almost all of these classes can be replaced with a test-specific DI container. You'll only have to register low-level individual test/mock objects, not their dependencies. The DI will take care of constructing the high-level objects from those dependencies

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, the test does not exist to fail yet.  I'm adding tests to prevent future regressions.  The only thing I _really_ want to mock out is `DocuSignCallbackHandler`.  Everything else, I want to be able to completely ignore, writing no code test code which directly references or otherwise acknowledges the existence of those classes (at least not in the context of the current tests or anything which I need to depend on for the current tests).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, the project is using net5.0.  I'm not entirely certain how to answer which DI container we are using.  I know all the dependencies get itemized in Startup.cs, if that helps.

Comment: You can use a DI Container as a [Auto-Mocking Container](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/03/11/auto-mocking-container/) in your tests. Take a look at [this example](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/290#issuecomment-243244930) for Simple Injector, for instance. That said, I do agree with the sentiment of the other commenters. The problem you're having is caused by design issues in your code.

Comment: @Steven, I'll check this later.  Thanks.

Comment: Alternative approach is not to use mocks at all ;)